# MSSQL Group concatenation adding columns as agroup by

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table Structure

```
Item, Group, Min Qty, Price
A,    1,     10,      1.00
A,    2,     10,      0.75
B,    1,     20,      0.90
C,    3,     5,       5.00
```

Sql query I am running currently which works for all the groups into 1 column, I'm trying to work out how I add a column for each group and only put in the values from that group only.

```
SELECT  [Item],
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + CAST([Min Qty] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ':' + CAST([Price] AS VARCHAR(MAX)  + ';')
    FROM [Table] WHERE ([Item No_] = Results.[Item] and [Minimum Qty] > '1') 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE 
    ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') 
  ,1,2,'') as Values
FROM    [Table] Results
GROUP BY [Item]
```

Current output

```
Item, Values
A,    10:0.75; 10:1.00; 
B,    20:0.90;
C,    5:5.00;
```

Required output

```
Item, Group 1,    Group 2,    Group 3
A,    10:1.00;    10:0.75;
B,    20:0.90; 
C,                            5:5.00;
```

Thank you for input

Edit from below

We don't know all the column names as they will be added by other users to the system, so needs to auto add the columns also should be grouping all entries for that group/item into 1 column as I'm trying to produce an output file.

Table information

```
Item, Group, Min Qty, Price
A,    1,     10,      1.00
A,    2,     10,      0.75
B,    1,     20,      0.90
C,    3,     5,       5.00
A,    1,     20,      0.50

Item, Group 1,           Group 2,    Group 3
A,    10:1.00;20:0.50;   10:0.75;
B,    20:0.90; 
C,                                    5:5.00;
```

Comment: You'll have to `GROUP BY Item, Group` and then do three seperate selects to get concatenated values. Alternatively, you can create `CLR Aggregate` function to concatenate things for you. Code here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2022/concat-aggregates-sql-server-clr-function/ You won't have to join your table three times then.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @t table (Item Varchar(2),Groups Varchar(2),MInqty varchar(10),Price Money)
insert into @t (Item,Groups,MInqty,Price)values 
('A,','1,',10,1.00),
('A,','2,',10,0.75),
('B,','1,',20,0.90),
('C,','3,',5,5.00)

select Item,[1,] AS [Groups 1],[2,] AS [Groups 2],[3,] AS [Groups 3]
 from (
select Item,Groups,MInqty  +':'+ CAST(price AS VARCHAR) + ';' As GRP from @t)P
PIVOT (MIN(GRP) FOR GROUPS IN ([1,],[2,],[3,]))PVT
```

Remodified answer check

```
Select Item,[1] AS [Groups 1],[2] AS [Groups 2],[3] AS [Groups 3] from (
Select P.Item,MIN(R)G,P.Value from (
SELECT   [Item],SUBSTRING(Groups,0,CHARINDEX(',',Groups))R,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + CAST([MInqty] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ':' + CAST([Price] AS VARCHAR(MAX)  )+';'As Grp
    FROM #t WHERE ([Item] = Results.[Item] and [MInqty] > '1') 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE 
    ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') 
  ,1,2,'') as Value
FROM    #t Results
GROUP BY Groups,Item)P
GROUP BY P.Item,p.Value)PP
PIVOT (MIN(Value)FOR G IN ([1],[2],[3]) )PVT
```

Comment: Sorry re-revised question as missed a little bit of information.

Comment: @LeeFarmer as per requirement i have answered the question again you have remodiifed the question and asking it's better to post new question

Comment: apologies new to posting q's will break them out in future